# Group by array contents

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-group

I have a `List<Tuple<string,long,byte[]>>` and I want to group by the contents of the byte array.

Is there a simple way to do this with `GroupBy` and a lambda?

Ideally, I want to do this without creating an intermediate data structure (like a string to hold the elements of the array).

Comment: What are you hoping to end up with? If you get the individual byte items as the key, what would the rest of your result be?

Comment: I'm hoping to end up with the items in my list grouped by the contents of that array. I.e. if the arrays are equal, then they are in the same group, otherwise they are in different groups.

Comment: Are you defining equality for the arrays as being a reference to the same array, or having the same bytes in different arrays?  If the latter, you need to define a custom equality comparer for `byte[]`.

Comment: @Servy, second one. How can I do that in the lambda?

Comment: @soandos You can't.  You need to create a new class that implements `IEqualityComparer<byte[]>`, implement both methods, create an instance of it, and pass that to `GroupBy`.

Comment: @Servy why not, and so how can I do it?

Comment: @soandos You could use `IEnumerable<T>.SequenceEqual()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx)

Comment: @itsme86 You also need to get a hash code.

Comment: @itsme86 how can I use that in the context of the lambda though? I only have one argument. Servy, the hashcode for arrays is just as good as the reference equality compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that using custom `IEqualityComparer<byte[]>` (or even better, generic one: `IEqualityComparer<T[]>`) implementation:

```
class ArrayComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T[]>
{
    public bool Equals(T[] x, T[] y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T[] obj)
    {
        return obj.Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, i) => s + i.GetHashCode(), s => s.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure `GetHashCode` could be implemented much better, but it's just an example!

**Usage:**

```
var grouped = source.GroupBy(i => i.Item3, new ArrayComparer<byte>())
```

Comment: That's not a very efficient hash code generation method, but it will work.

Comment: As I said - it's just an example.

Comment: Well odds are the OP isn't going to know that your GetHashCode method isn't very good, or how to fix it; he's just going to test it once or twice, see the right output, and never touch it again.

Comment: What is the GetHashCode method used for (as opposed to equals)?

Comment: @soandos It's well described on MSDN: [`Object.GetHashCode` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx)

Comment: How is it handled if the hashcodes are equal, but the objects are not? (I will be using this in a case where there are at least 600,000 objects or so)

Comment: @soandos It uses `Equals` to determine if they are *actually* equal when the hashes collide.

Comment: `Equals` method is used then.

Comment: So in essence, the hash code does not have to be very good if the arrays are short (the time it takes to create the strings would be much higher if the array is only of size 4 or so)?

Comment: @soandos The hash code never *has* to be good.  How good it is determines how efficient the operation is.  In this case, the hash code is time and memory consuming to create, and has a much higher rate of collisions than it could have.  These are all bad properties for a hash code.  None of them will result in incorrect output, just slow execution as the size of the data as well as the number of items increases.

Comment: @Servy make sense. I think I'm going to profile the results of this hashing function with just `return obj[0]` since in my case those are random, and the equals check is short.

Comment: @soandos It could be a good idea. You're gonna iterate within `Equals` method then (for same first element), pretty the same time consumable as calculating `HashCode` from whole array content.

Comment: @Servy Can you propose a better `GetHashCode` implementation?

Comment: @julealgon It's a pretty well solved problem; a bit of basic research on the subject will result in a number of simple well suited algorithms for different situations.

Comment: @Servy But it would've saved us all time and helped complete this answer to just suggest what you feel is the best solution for this situation in the first place.