# LINQ solution to count occurrences of IEnumerable<int> in a List

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

I have a `List<IEnumerable<int>>`. I want to count how many occurrences of each `IEnumerable<int>` there are in the list. For example:

```
using System.Linq;
List<IEnumerable<int>> list = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();
    list.Add(new int[] { 5 }.AsEnumerable() );
    list.Add(new int[] { 7, 8 }.AsEnumerable());
    list.Add(new int[] { 5 }.AsEnumerable());
    list.Add(new int[] { 5 }.AsEnumerable());
    list.Add(new int[] { 9 }.AsEnumerable());
    list.Add(new int[] { 4 }.AsEnumerable());
```

This `list` has `3` `IEnumerable<int>s` with value of `5`, and `1` occurrence of the other elements.

I've tried:

```
var one = list.ToArray().GroupBy(i => i).ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ToArray(), x => x.Count());
var two = list.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

foreach(var item in one) { //or two
    Console.WriteLine("key {0} .. item {1}",
    string.Join(", ", item.Key.ToArray()),
    item.Value);
}
```

Unfortunately both of these all result in `1` as the number of occurrences (even though the `IEnumerable<int>s` with value of `5` have `3` occurrences).

Any suggestions to try?

**EDIT**

As MarcinJuraszek pointed out: "You'd have to define a custom comparer because default comparer for IEnumerable will do a reference equality."
The reason I was getting all 1's was because it was searching the addresses in memory, which are all different. To get around this without writing a custom comparer I did this:

```
var dict = list.GroupBy(x => string.Format(", ", x.ToArray()) ).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

Comment: You'd have to define a custom comparer because default comparer for `IEnumerable<T>` will do a reference equality.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, I think you already answered this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841178/group-by-array-contents

Comment: Something like `var results = list.SelectMany().GroupBy(x=>x).Select(x=>new {x.Key, x.Count});`

Comment: @RobertMcKee That gives you the count of the number of values in inner sequences, not the number of sequences that are equal.

Comment: My bad, I thought that is what he wanted.  I see now he's looking to group entire sequences and their count.